# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 check if current user is in role IsInRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

With ASP.NET Identity 2.0 how do you check if the currently logged on user is in a role?  I am using the following, but wondering if there is something more efficient.

```
var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DbContext()));
var au = um.FindByEmail(Context.User.Identity.GetUserName());
var inrole = um.IsInRole(au.Id, "Admin");

if (inrole)
{
}
```

Answer (score 41):

The correct way in ASP Identity is as simple as

```
User.IsInRole("rolename");
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works if the user is logged in.

Comment: What do you mean? The question is about the current logged in user. There is other ways to query about roles for a user who is not logged in

Comment: I suppose this way will check roles in ClaimsIdentity. For instance, if User1 is logged in and after that you will add User1 to Group1 User1.IsInRole("Group1") = false. User1 needs to logout-login.

Comment: For this to work with JWT Authentication, you have to first add the roles in the ClaimsIdentity as mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036810/asp-net-core-jwt-mapping-role-claims-to-claimsidentity

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are in ASP.NET, it's pretty simple:

```
if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Administrators"))
{
  return "You are not authorized to access this page.";
)
```

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can get the user id from the Identity rather than having to lookup the user in the database...

```
var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DbContext()));
var inrole = um.IsInRole(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId(), "Admin");
```

Comment: um.IsInRole calls IsInRoleAsync, that is checking the database I think

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me hope this helps...

```
If HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin") Then
        adminmnu.Visible = True
    End If
```

Comment: This question is tagged for C# yet you answered using VB.NET